# Slow Internet / Can't change brightness on 2010 Macbook AIr running 12.10 Ubuntu

Tags: brightness, macbook-air

The title really says it all. I haven't been able to change the brightness of my monitor since putting Ubuntu on it. I started off with 12.04 and then decided to see if 12.10 would fix the issue. The internet is also a fair bit slower than I am used to, especially when downloading. Apart from these two issues, everything goes very smoothly.

If anyone could offer any advice or solutions, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I am also using the Broadcom driver for my wi-fi. And the proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for not providing an answer, but I have a question for you. What tutorial did you follow and what other issues did you experience? I want to do the same thing (latest Ubuntu on a late 2010 Macbook Air 3.2).

There seem to be so many old and half finished tutorials out there that I am unsure how to proceed. Is there a definitive write-up that can be trusted?

Good luck with your issues, I will be checking back.

BTW did you check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir3-2/Meerkat):

Look for EnableBrightnessControl

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I had the same problem, and the pointer of "Roy Prins" helped me. 
You can ignore all previous "guidelines". 12.10 works out of box, without any "post-install things". But the only problem is, with nvidia-driver, you lost the backlight control. (That was the only problem I had, on my 2010 macbook air 11 inch. If I use nuoveau driver, it has the backlight, but some vertical lines comes up. So using NVidia driver is the best bet for Macbook Air 3,1.)

The solution for backlight is simple. As Roy pointed out, add option for "EnableBrightnessControl". For example, my /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
tailblues@gilsaire:/etc/X11$ cat xorg.conf
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Default Device"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    Option      "NoLogo"    "True"
    Option      "RegistryDwords"    "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
    BusID       "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection
tailblues@gilsaire:/etc/X11$
```

And then, it started working for me!